# Where am i going wrong in solving this equation?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, quadratics, discriminant

> Fing the least value of $a$ for which $f(x)$ is increasing, where
>   $$f(x)=2e^x-ae^{-x}+(2a+1)x-3$$

**What i tried**

for increasing $f'(x)\ge 0, \forall x\in \mathbb R$. So $$f'(x)=2e^x+ae^{-x}+2a+1\geq0$$ and multiplying through by $e^x$ we  get$$f'(x)=2e^{2x}+a+(2a+1)e^x\ge0$$and now put $y=e^x$

$$\implies2y^2+(2a+1)y+a\ge0$$ So discriminant ($D$) of this equation should be less than $0$
$$D=4a^2-4a+1\leq 0\implies(2a-1)^2\leq0$$which is only true when $a=1/2$, but this is not the correct answer! The least value of $a$ required is $0$ and $f(x)$ is increasing for $a\in[0,\infty[$ but my equation says it increases only if $a=1/2$

So where am i going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm sorry, but how did you get from the line with $f'(x) = \ldots$ to $2y^2 + \ldots$?

Comment: Where did the x in your original equation suddenly disappear in the next step

Comment: Note:  since $e^x$ is always positive you don't need the quadratic to have no real roots, you just need it to have no positive roots.

Comment: @shardulc in $f'(x)$ put $e^x$ as $y$

Comment: @ramsay Then I get $2y + \frac{a}{y} +2a + 1 \geq 0$.

Comment: @shardulc  Yes, and then multiply through by $y$ to get the OP's form.  As $y$ is always positive this does not change the inequality.

Comment: @lulu Oh... I guess I was being a little slow

Comment: @ramsay  To elaborate on my earlier comment, the problem with your method is that it doesn't matter if the quadratic has roots or not, it only matters if there is a non-negative root. If, say, $a=.25$ then the roots are $y=\{-.25,-.125\}$.  As both of these are negative there is no $x$ such that $e^x=y$, so they don't matter.

Comment: @lulu i didn't understand sorry! but wtih $d\leq 0$ we say that this equation can either have one root or no root. So it must provide me an answer but it doesn't, i don't know why?

Comment: Your method is conceptually flawed.  As you point out, this quadratic always has roots, for any value of $a$.  So what?  If both roots happen to be non-positive then $e^x$ can't actually be either of the roots...that's the point.  Use the quadratic formula to find both roots and you'll see for which $a$ there might be a positive root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So where am i going wrong?

In the following part :

> $$\implies2y^2+(2a+1)y+a\ge0$$ So discriminant ($D$) of this equation should be less than $0$

Note that $y\ (=e^x)$ is **positive**. So, what we want is the condition for $a$ that $2y^2+(2a+1)y+a\ge 0$ holds for every **positive** $y$. (That you had $D\le 0$ means that you found the condition for $a$ that $2y^2+(2a+1)y+a\ge 0$ holds for *every* $y$, including non-positive $y$).

We can write
$$F(y):=2y^2+(2a+1)y+a=2\left(y+\frac{2a+1}{4}\right)^2-\frac{(2a-1)^2}{8}$$

The vertex of the parabola $Y=F(y)$ is $(-(2a+1)/4,-(2a-1)^2/8)$ where $-(2a-1)^2/8\le 0$.

We have to have $$-\frac{2a+1}{4}\lt 0\quad \text{and}\quad F(0)\ge 0\iff a\ge 0$$
and this is sufficient.

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

Comment: This is the only answer which points out the problem in OP's solution. +1

Comment: finally someone came up with reason, this made me happy thank you! be ready to get 50

Answer (score 1):

So you want $f'(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$, which led to:
$$2e^x+ae^{-x}+2a+1 \ge 0 \iff 2e^{2x}+\left(2a+1\right)e^x+a\ge 0$$
If you factor this:
$$\left(2e^x+1\right)\left(e^x+a\right)\ge 0$$
The first factor is always positive and $e^x+a \ge 0$ for all $x$ if $a \ge 0$.

Comment: "but what is wrong in my steps" that is my question?

Comment: I think the last statement should be "iff $a \geq 0$" to answer the question rigorously. If $a < 0$, then for some very negative $x$, $e^x + a < 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Notes:
1) $y>0$ everywhere;
2) when $D<0,$ then $y>0$ everywhere.

Factorization is the right way, and we have to resolve inequality
$$f'(x) = e^{-x}(2e^x+1)(e^x+a)\geq0,$$
$$e^x+a\geq 0.$$
If $a\geq0,$ then $f(x)$ increases everywhere.
If $a<0$, then $f(x)$ increases with $x\in(\ln(-a),\infty).$